# How to disable a minor/major mode so that mwheel-scroll don’t take effect?

Tags: major-mode, minor-mode, scrolling

I am trying to have a simple solution to center the cursor at all times. I found that `centered-cursor-mode` was too slow and found this simpler solution.
The only problem is mouse scrolling no longer works unless I disable the minor/major mode I implemented to center the cursor.

I tried to advise `mwheel-scroll` to disable the mode but that was unsuccessful. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
(define-minor-mode centered-point-mode
  "Always center the cursor on the screen."
  :lighter "..."
  (cond (centered-point-mode (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'line-change))
    (t (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'line-change))))

(defun line-change ()
  (recenter))

(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-centered-point-mode centered-point-mode
  (lambda () (centered-point-mode 1)))
(my-global-centered-point-mode 1)

(defun disable-centered
  (interactive)
  (centered-point-mode -1))

(advice-add 'mwheel-scroll :before (lambda () (interactive) (call-interactively 'disable-centered)))
```

Comment: No need for any `advice-...`, as far as I can see.  How about putting in exceptions for `line-change`?  E.g., `(unless (eq this-command 'mwheel-scroll) (recenter))`  If you want multiple exceptions, use `(unless (memq this-command '(mwheel-scroll foo-command bar-command baz-command)) (recenter))`  In most cases, `this-command` is the command of the current command loop -- however, certain hooks run after `this-command` becomes the `last-command` even though the command loop is still the same ... but, the `post-command-hook` is early enough in time so that `this-command` is still current.

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O.P. has indicated in a comment underneath the original question that a previous suggestion by this author resolved the issue, and this answer is a write-up of that solution....  There is no need to use any `advice-...`.  Instead, the O.P. could use one of two potential conditions:

1. For just one exception, modify the function `line-change` as follows:

```lisp
(unless (eq this-command 'mwheel-scroll)
  (recenter))
```

2. For multiple exceptions, modify the function `line-change` as follows:

```lisp
(unless (memq this-command '(mwheel-scroll foo-command bar-command baz-command))
  (recenter))
```

In most cases, `this-command` is the command of the current command loop -- however, certain hooks run after `this-command` becomes the `last-command` even though the command loop is still the same ... but, the `post-command-hook` is early enough in time so that `this-command` is still current.

Comment: As a follow up, now mouse scrolling works but the cursor moves around then recenters when moving with arrows. Is there a way to make mouse scrolling works while also fixing the cursor position?

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, please edit the question and tags to no longer speak of "advice" and advising. IOW, it that's not really part of the question then please remove it. Thx.

Comment: I would suggest that you launch a *new* question/thread to deal with:  "*[T]he cursor moves around then recenters when moving with arrows ... [i]s there a way to make mouse scrolling works while also fixing the cursor position?*"  It may behoove you to spend some time explaining exactly what you see and how you wish to change the behavior, and perhaps some code of what you have already tried.

Comment: Note that the second example in the answer above containing the `memq` statement is for situations where you have multiple exceptions.  E.g., replace `foo-command` with `left-char`, and replace `bar-command` with `right-char`.  To see which functions are assigned to certain keystrokes, type:  `C-h k` and then perform the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Drew, done. Lawlist, will write a new post and explain the new issue I am facing.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54710/how-to-scroll-using-mouse-while-keeping-cursor-on-same-line-position

Comment: Lawlist, with the above solution all works well except when trying to start a new emacs instance I get this error: *ERROR*: ‘recenter’ing a window that does not display current-buffer.