# How to scroll using mouse while keeping cursor on same line/position?

Tags: mouse, scrolling, cursor

I am using this minor mode to scroll and keep cursor on same line, `mwheel-scroll` however screws up the smooth scroll since it moves the cursor to a different line, scrolling return the cursor back to original line but the visual is not smooth.

I tried:

```
scroll-preserve-screen-position 'always
```

But that didn't help.

This is the minor mode I am using:

```
(define-minor-mode centered-point-mode
  "Always center the cursor in the 1/3rd of the screen."
  :lighter "..."
  (cond (centered-point-mode (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'line-change))
    (t (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'line-change))))

(setq recenter-positions '(0.35))
(defun line-change ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (memq this-command '(mwheel-scroll mac-mwheel-scroll)) 
   (recenter-top-bottom)))

(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-centered-point-mode centered-point-mode
  (lambda () (centered-point-mode 1)))
(my-global-centered-point-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the built-in `scroll-lock-mode` to your code, you should get behavior like what you want.

Here's a slightly more-expansive update to your mode that fixes two other issues I found (the buffer-local version works normally and it doesn't change `recenter-positions` globally). Following your comments, I've also updated it not to rely directly on `scroll-lock-mode`, so it doesn't add any key bindings.

```el
(defcustom centered-point-position 0.35
  "Percentage of screen where `centered-point-mode' keeps point."
  :type 'float)

(setq centered-point--preserve-pos nil)

(define-minor-mode centered-point-mode
  "Keep the cursor at `centered-point-position' in the window"
  :lighter " centerpoint"
  (cond (centered-point-mode (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'center-point nil t)
                             (setq centered-point--preserve-pos
                                   scroll-preserve-screen-position)
                             (setq-local scroll-preserve-screen-position 'all))
        (t (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'center-point t)
           (setq-local scroll-preserve-screen-position
                       centered-point--preserve-pos))))


(defun center-point ()
  "Move point to the line at `centered-point-position'."
  (interactive)
  (when (eq (current-buffer) (window-buffer))
    (let ((recenter-positions (list centered-point-position)))
      (recenter-top-bottom))))

(defun centered-point-mode-on ()
  (centered-point-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-centered-point-mode centered-point-mode
  centered-point-mode-on)
```

Then use `(global-centered-point-mode 1)` to enable the mode globally.

[`centered-mouse-mode`](https://github.com/andre-r/centered-cursor-mode.el) seems to provide this functionality, so you might want to take a look at that as well.

Comment: I came across another problem. I use Ivy and when searching and trying to go through match candidates in the minibuffer C-n is now mapped to scroll-lock-next-line which doesnt move the cursor to the next line. Where when disabling the mode C-n is mapped to ivy-next-line. How to fix that?

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Instead of using `scroll-lock-mode`, it now uses the same variable that mode does, so it doesn't use `scroll-lock-mode-map`, and no keys are rebound at all.

Comment: jirassimok, Your implementation has been going strong and no issues. But today I decided to use my macbook and found that the laptop mouse scrolling doesn't work properly. I have the scrolling on the mouse mapped to mac-mwheel-scroll. Is it possible to have that fixed? Much appreciation.

Comment: You think I should go back to doing this: (unless (memq this-command '(mwheel-scroll mac-mwheel-scroll)) ? I feel this would not be efficient.

Comment: I don't have `mac-mwheel-scroll`. If you're having problems with that, I recommend asking a new question so someone else can help you. The simplest solution is probably to just rebind the scroll "keys" to the commands you want.

Comment: I am curious what is different for a Mac mouse that it doesn't follow the same scroll-lock-mode like a regular external mouse. I will ask the question in a separate thread. Thanks.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54891/mac-mwheel-scroll-screws-centered-positon-mode-when-using-mouse-pad-on-a-macbook